# Foreman start results in server error 500

Tags: python, django, heroku, gunicorn, foreman

I am following Getting Started with Django on Heroku tutorial to deploy my app. First to test locally, I ran foreman start:

```
| => foreman start
00:47:08 web.1  | started with pid 4465
00:47:09 web.1  | 2013-11-21 00:47:09 [4465] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 18.0
00:47:09 web.1  | 2013-11-21 00:47:09 [4465] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (4465)
00:47:09 web.1  | 2013-11-21 00:47:09 [4465] [INFO] Using worker: sync
00:47:09 web.1  | 2013-11-21 00:47:09 [4468] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 4468
```

Then in Chrome I went to `http://0.0.0.0:5000/rides/` (also `http://localhost:5000/rides/`), it is returning Server Error 500. 
My project urls.py:

```
url(r'^rides/', include('rides.urls')),
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

Below is my Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn rides_project.wsgi
```

requirements.txt:

```
Django==1.6
South==0.8.3
dj-database-url==0.2.2
dj-static==0.0.5
django-localflavor==1.0
django-toolbelt==0.0.1
gunicorn==18.0
psycopg2==2.5.1
static==0.4
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

How can I troubleshoot this? Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you navigate to /admin successfully? If so, I would ensure that your [DEBUG](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#debug%20%22debug%20setting%22%20is)  setting is set to True so that you can get a traceback through the browser to help determine the root cause of the 500 error.

Comment: You are right. I had turned Debug off. When I turned it on:

settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the NAME value
In my settings.py, I had put this at the top:
`
try: 
    from local_settings import *
except Exception as e:
    pass`
Apparently, it should have been placed at the bottom of the file. That allowed me to test my app locally with Gunicorn with Foreman.